# Using the UWP to open a runfulltrust desktop application breaks the desktop application

Tags: c#, file, uwp, parent-child, desktop-application

This really does not make any sense. I have a UWP application, titled `FirstUWP`. It opens fine on its own.

I have a desktop extension that I made called `scrren.exe`, taking advantage of tesseract to read some image from the screen. When first opening my UWP and then opening up the `scrren.exe` on it's own, both run fine.

However, when I use the runfulltrust launcher from UWP, the `scrren.exe` cannot write to a file that is under the UWP's project.

When they are launched entirely separately, the `scrren.exe` can write to the folder fine, it is just when the UWP launches it the `scrren.exe` cannot write to the folder within the UWP.

This code is the place where the problem occurs within the Desktop Extension `sccren.exe`. I've also attached a screenshot showing the Assets tree within the UWP, showing the Images folder which seems to be where my problems originate. Below that, I attached a screenshot showing what I mean that when launched from within UWP, `scrren.exe` shows up under the UWPs parent name, but this is where I get errors and `scrren.exe` cannot write to the `Images` folder.

I really hope this makes sense.

```
string result = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
int index = result.LastIndexOf("\\");
string rootPath = $"{result.Substring(0, index)}\\..\\";

using (Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap1))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }

    try
    {
        using (bitmap1)
        {
            bitmap1.Save((rootPath + @"Scrn\Images\test.png"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "Right here");
    }

    // Sleep for one second in order to let the file properly save
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

[image: This image shows my asset tree within the UWP, including the Images folder]

[image]

Comment: Is there any error message when you are trying to create the file？

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to a packaged app's install location; it is read-only. Instead you should be using [`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localfolder?view=winrt-22000) to get the local folder for saving files.

Also make sure you are using [`FullTrustProcessLauncher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-22000) to launch your exe, not something like `Process.Start()`.